# Can I disable console logging for all chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm a web developer, so I use the js console a lot to debug my web apps, but the extensions I prefer to use on Chrome write a lot of junk to the console. I don't want to have to disable all my extensions while working because I'm switching back and forth a lot. I could use user switching(on my OS) I know, but that's a pain too because again I'm switching back and forth allot.

I really want to just prevent any extensions from using the console period as I never need to see output from extensions, is their a way to do this? If not is there a way to quickly turn off all extensions and then back on, say by having some type of fast profile switching within chrome itself?

Just to be clear these are not extensions I write, these are ones I download that I want to prevent from using the console.

Comment: you could create a new profile from Chrome just for your testing.

Answer (score 4):

Chrome itself features user profiles and fast user switching. Add a user from  `chrome://settings/`.

You can test your webapp from the new user you created.

[image]

Switching between users is just a matter of clicking on the icon on the top left and then select the other user

[image]

Comment: Thanks this helps allot, I thought something like this was there I just couldn't find it. However I'll still leave my original question up as to weather or not there is a way to prevent all extensions from logging to the console. If I don't get an answer in a week I'll mark this as accepted. I upvoted you though.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the above answer, you could also use an `Incognito` or `Private` tab to silence those extensions... but there are drawbacks... for example when `Visual Studio` launches a debug window it will use the last active browser window to add its new debugging tab... so you have to make sure the `Incognito` window is active/selected.

As far as your actual question, I am fairly certain the answer is no. The log is not meant for users but for devs and an extension being able to silence logs might be a security violation. It would have to be a feature specifically added to the browser, perhaps a checkbox list of extensions that you could manually uncheck? `Chromium` is `open source` so if you had the skills and time, **you** could add it.